# Zimbra id messages script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I hope I can explain what I want to do, I am creating a script for zimbra that allows me to capture the ID of the messages of each user and get it in a txt extension file, and the command that allows me to do this is as follows:

```
zmmailbox -z -m info@domain.com search -l 2 "in:/inbox"
```

this command outputs the following:

num: 2, more: true

```
  Id  Type   From                  Subject           Date
```

---

1. -482  conv   Twitter               Kevin K. Sullivan twitteó: Muy emocionado de poder  06/14/22 06:02
2. -481  conv   Twitter               Netto, únete a la conversación ya mismo     06/10/22 05:15

now what I need is to be able to add another column where I can add the user that is affecting the script.

```
num: 2, more: true

  Id  Type   From                  Subject           Date         User
```

---

1. -482  conv   Twitter               Kevin K. Sullivan twitteó: Muy emocionado de poder  06/14/22 06:02   info@domain.com
2. -481  conv   Twitter               Netto, únete a la conversación ya mismo     06/10/22 05:15 info@domain.com

I publish the actual script.

https://pastebin.com/7S1uFcY3

Comment: sorry for the delay, I did not get much done, https://pastebin.com/7S1uFcY3